# Is every planar point set the projection of vertices of a neighborly 4-polytope?

Tags: co.combinatorics, convex-polytopes, oriented-matroids

More exactly, written in coordinates, I'm curious to know if for every point set $(x_i,y_i)$ there are $(x_i,y_i,z_i,w_i)$ that are vertices of a neighborly polytope.

This problem comes from a simple observation: every planar point set is projection of a convex 3-polytope. One can lift $(x,y)\mapsto (x,y,x^2+y^2)$ as the inverse of projection.

There is the oriented matroid version of such problem, can topes of every acyclic rank-3 uniform oriented matroid realized as a subset of topes of rank-5 neighborly oriented matroid? (<del>I'm also not very sure the whether taking subset and projection is always the same</del>, this is the strong map conjecture) I'm looking for contour examples for both problem.

Comment: The parabolic lift map "works" in arbitrary dimensions, which does not directly answer your question, but...

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke I've tried to construct a "neighborly" surface embedded in R^4, which should have properties that the line connecting two points in the surface should be intersection of tangent planes of two point, and I believe the surface (x,y,x^2+y^2,x^2+y^2+(x^2+y^2)^2) do not have such properties.

Comment: OK, @Belanov, I see that I haven't fully considered your *neighborly* requirement. My oversight.